# MS Office shortcuts no longer available

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

I'm unable to run any MS Office application from the Start menu shortcuts. Notepad, Visual Studio and others seem to be OK but, strangely, Adobe Reader X is not. Looking into the shortcut properties I see that the "Target" field is empty. Clicking on these shortcuts yields the error dialog "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed". Trying to repair the installation via the Control Panel brings up the error dialog "This product installation has been corrupted. Run setup again from the CD, DVD, or other original installation source."

I currently have no access to an original installation source so is there any other way to resolve this? I guess I can reenter the shortcuts manually but I'm afraid of breaking something.

This is on a Windows 7 machine running Office 2010 Professional Plus.

Comment: You could try a System Restore and see if that resolve it?

Comment: You need to reinstall any program with this error.  Have you tried run say Word by hand by running Word.exe in the Office installation directory?

Comment: @DaveRook I just found out system restore was disabled on my computer :-(

Comment: @Ramhound running Office apps manually works OK.

Comment: Johnny, in that case, the issue is with the short cuts? Well done to Ramhound! :)

Comment: @Johnny - Create new shortcuts yourself and place them on the desktop.  Delete the old shortcuts since they are no longer valid.

Comment: @Johnny, is this issue resolved now?

Comment: @DaveRook, sadly no. The IT here have decided to install a new disk image. Excessive, but that's how they roll.